# How to change password and login in Jenkins, if no password or username are found in jenkins.xml?

Tags: authentication, jenkins, passwords

```
Hi.I have installed a Jenkins 2.423 from the https://www.jenkins.io/download/ . Couldn't install LTS version of Jenkins (it can't open a required localhost, which I write during the installation).As I've installed it on my computer before, - there could be a Jenkins account before. But, then I deleted Jenkins. And all files which were left in the "Jenkins" folder.After deletion, I've needed it again. So I downloaded it, and opened the localhost. Now it has input fields for the username and password. I've inputed a password and username from the Jenkins site, but could not log in. I've used my username from Windows, and password, and tried to log in. It did not worked.I've searched for the solution in the Internet, and via Bing A.I..People write that some part of the jenkins.xml should be edited. Thi is what it contains now:`<!--
The MIT License

Copyright (c) 2004-2017, Sun Microsystems, Inc., Kohsuke Kawaguchi, Oleg Nenashev, and other Jenkins contributors

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy
of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal
in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights
to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell
copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is
furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in
all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR
IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY,
FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE
AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER
LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM,
OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN
THE SOFTWARE.
-->
<!--
  Windows service definition for Jenkins.

  To uninstall, run "jenkins.exe stop" to stop the service, then "jenkins.exe uninstall" to uninstall the service.
  Both commands don't produce any output if the execution is successful. 
-->
<service>
  <id>jenkins</id>
  <name>Jenkins</name>
  <description>This service runs Jenkins automation server.</description>
  <env name="JENKINS_HOME" value="%ProgramData%\Jenkins\.jenkins"/>
  <!--
    if you'd like to run Jenkins with a specific version of Java, specify a full path to java.exe.
    The following value assumes that you have java in your PATH.
  -->
  <executable>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-21\bin\java.exe</executable>
  <arguments>-Xrs -Xmx256m -Dhudson.lifecycle=hudson.lifecycle.WindowsServiceLifecycle -jar "C:\Program Files\Jenkins\jenkins.war" --httpPort=8084 --webroot="%ProgramData%\Jenkins\war"</arguments>
  <!--
    interactive flag causes the empty black Java window to be displayed.
    I'm still debugging this.
  <interactive />
  -->
  <logmode>rotate</logmode>

  <onfailure action="restart"/>
  
  <!-- 
    In the case WinSW gets terminated and leaks the process, we want to abort
    these runaway JAR processes on startup to prevent corruption of JENKINS_HOME.
    So this extension is enabled by default.
  -->
  <extensions>
    <!-- This is a sample configuration for the RunawayProcessKiller extension. -->
    <extension enabled="true" className="winsw.Plugins.RunawayProcessKiller.RunawayProcessKillerExtension" id="killOnStartup">
      <pidfile>%ProgramData%\Jenkins\jenkins.pid</pidfile>
      <stopTimeout>10000</stopTimeout>
      <stopParentFirst>false</stopParentFirst>
    </extension>
  </extensions>
  
  <!-- See the referenced examples for more options -->
  
</service>`
```

And adding `<useSecurity>False</useSecurity>` and changing it into the `<useSecurity>True</useSecurity>` did not helped, as I don't know where it should be added.
Also I don't know how to generate new hashcode, and where to add it with the `<passwordHash> </passwordHash>`
in the jenkins.xml.
Please help me to change my username and password in Jenkins.

1. Added `<useSecurity>False</useSecurity>` and changing it into the `<useSecurity>True</useSecurity>` in the random places of the jenkins.xml.
2. Using my username and password from the Jenkins website.
3. Using my username and password from Windows.
4. deleting the Jenkins from the computer, cleaning all previously created Jenkins files and re-installing it again.
5. Creating a separate new user on the Windows, which could use a separate Jenkins.
6. Using a docker Jenkins.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).